# mongoDB cant see certain req values in Express page

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Have an object coming into the route, and makes it to the page:
When I view the whole object like:

```
 {{userdata}}
```

I can see the whole object, with the values I'm trying to get, and its all there. I can uniquely get data like username and phone etc from this object, but there are other values that are in there such as:

{{verified}} and {{vericode}} which will not show up when I try to individually access them.
The keys are in there, can see {{userdata.username}} but not {{userdata.verified}} or {{userdata.vericode}}

```
{
    "_id" : 5a57afc7b742153776d8afb4,
    "active" : true,
    "since" : 2017-12-03T07:02:25.000Z,
    "name" : "sidx",
    "username" : "sidx",
    "password" : "aPWGOESHERE",
    "phone" : "1234567890",
    "priv" : [
        true
    ],
    "internalnotes" : "",
    "phone3" : "2662626262",
    "phone2" : "4534523452",
    "verified" : "true",
    "vericode" : "true",
    "active_repairs" : [ ],
    "service_history" : [ ],
    "email" : [
        "imam@sumone.com"
    ]
}
```

Hope someone can give some insight. Seems like a bug to me maybe. All values are being stored properly in the db, and can get them to express route to the html. but not individually with those particular elements.

Below this line is what is in the handlebars.

```
 Welcome {{user.username}}, to your Dashboard.   <!-- shows username ok!-->

 {{user}}    <!-- shows whole obj with target values incl verified and vericode -->           
 {{user.since}}  <!-- ex. of working showing val like {{user.username}} -->
 {{user.verified}}  <!-- THIS DOES NOT SHOW -->  
 {{user.vericode}}   <!-- THIS DOES NOT SHOW -->
```

UPDATE to post output of {{user}}, please don't confuse my {{userdata}} as it was generic variable for {{user}} which is the same thing in this case.

This is what is shown on the page when I render, using:

```
 {{user}}
```

This would be rendered in browser view as below: 
(indented for format readability)::

```
 { 
  _id: 5a57afc7b742153776d8afb4, 
  active: true, 
  since: 2017-12-03T07:02:25.000Z, 
  name: 'sidx', 
  username: 'sidx', 
  password: '$2a$10$qWNYgAI4h1G9EZIQG!!PWHASH!!!mVaUXhbcZgXYZ123', 
  phone: '1234567890', 
  priv: [ true ], 
  internalnotes: 'These are the notes!', 
  phone3: '2662626262', 
  phone2: '4534523452', 
  verified: 'true', 
  vericode: 'true', 
  active_repairs: [], 
  service_history: [ [] ], 
  email: [ 'sid@sid.com' ] 
}
```

So it shows when I render the page this way, but simply shows nothing after page render when I do {{user.verified}} or {{user.vericode}}

I feel at this point I might need to look into what versions of XYZ I'm running. Unless there is a valid rhyme and reason why.

But for now, the data is writeable via an Users.update() using mongoose, and I can see the changes when I make, say, {{user.phone}} updates or {{user.internalnotes}} , and the changes will reflect when rendered in the page.

UPDATE (RESOLVED ISSUE):

I had to check the code that created the Schema instance:

```
  var newUser = new User({
    name: name,
    email: email,
    username: username,
    password: password,
    phone: phone,
    vericode: "false",    //Made sure this was set
    verified: "false",    // <----

  });
```

I also had to check the Model Schema and make sure it was OK from syntax errors. After the corrections the issue appears resolved.

Comment: are you not seeing those values saved in mongoDB? or in UI rendering?

Comment: I can verify them in mongo console, using db.users.find()
Shows the data. When I render {{userdata}} it list the object and everything the db reflects, including the keys im trying to get, aka 'verified' and 'vericode' ... I can see them when rendering the page using just {{userdata}} shows the whole doc with vericode and verified, but try rendering {{userdata.vericode}}  shows nothing. {{userdata.username}} etc are showing fine. The two 'vericode' and 'verified' are in Schema, saves to db, but manually added using db.users.update({...} {$set: {verified="true"} ) method. Hope thats more clear

Comment: yes, can you also post the UI code you are using for rendering?

Comment: Isn't it the string "false" which you get back and not the boolean false ? Did you check

Comment: Yes, it is a String literal "false" that is expected to return, as it is declared as a String within the Schema. As I'm now able to pinpoint the value I am wanting per the original question, as appearing as resolved. What still gets me wondering is why I was able to see the {{user}} elements as a whole, but not individually render those specific keys like {{user.verified}} value at the time. Found the fixed by fixing syntax and saving Schema, but wouldn't  'verified' and 'vericode' have not shown in that case when rendering {{user}} before that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is in rendering `Boolean` values in `Handlebars JS`

instead of

```
{{user.verified}}
```

change it to

```
{{#if user.verified}}
    true
{{else}}
    false
{{/if}}
```

same for `user.vericode`

[Demo - JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nsaravanas/7mdmwacn/1/)

Comment: The keys 'vericode' and 'verified' datatypes are string, not boolean. Same result occurs when I change it to a different value thats not 'true' or 'false'. An {{#if user.vericode}} does not see it a true, and will run it's {{else}} instead.

Comment: Can you post output of  {{user}}  ?

Answer (score 0):

Upon reviewing and editing the User Model Schema and checking the router.post that creates the Schema instance to then write to the db, I noticed it needed to be added with these Schema instance variables, then noticed same effect. I went to the User model, and ensured the Schema had the data, and then saved, to which the console err'd and informed me a syntax error in the User model user Schema, and was missing a Comma, after the "verified"..
I added this, saved and restarted the node server, and now I am seeing the desired result. I am curious as to why I was able to see it before in the rendered clump of {{user}}, but not individually. I suspect obviously the Schema setup had an effect, that I must come to grips of understanding with. Nice learning lesson here. SAVE!